# Pass object as parameter in Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `<Link>` and trying to pass in my `thumb_id`  (if I console log it is just a string value) to my `editvideo` page as a parameter. How do I accomplish this?

**Code Snippet**

```
const { thumbnail, _id } = this.props;

    return thumbnail.map(thumb => {
      console.log(thumb._id);

      return (
        <div key={thumb._id} className="row__inner">
          <Link to="/editvideo/:thumb._id">
            <div className="tile">
              <div className="tile__media">
                <img
                  className="tile__img"
                  id="thumbnail"
                  src={thumb.thumbnail}
                  alt=""
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
```

**Params using temp literal**

[image]

**Console log of `thumb_id`**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to insert the value of the variable in the string.

```
<Link to={`/editvideo/${thumb._id}`}>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that but the `thumb_id` itself is being passed as the param instead of the id (I updated my code and added a screenshot of my console)

Comment: @The_Enigma Do you want the `_id` from the props in all `Link` components, instead of the `thumb._id`?

Comment: I want it for a specific component. So pretty much my code generates thumbnail tiles. When I click on them I want to pass the `thumb._id` as a parameter to my page `Link` so then I can get data specific to that `id`.

Comment: I also updated my description with a screenshot of the console log of `thumb_.id` because I assumed since I just `console.log` it and its a string value I could do it was you suggested.

Comment: @The_Enigma Sorry, I don't quite understand. You can use either `_id` or `thumb._id` in the `Link`, and then get that id in the parameters of the component in `this.props.match.params.nameOfYourRouteParam`.

Comment: Well if I try it the way you suggested I get this as my param `$%7Bthumb._id%7D` , that's where I am having issues now instead of getting the logged value of `thumb._id` as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @The_Enigma You have to use template literals, `\``, not regular quote `'` or double quote `"`.

Comment: I LOVE YOU, I didn't freaking see that.